# CSS top menu bar

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to create a top menu bar like in stackoverflow (but with fixed position).

[**`JSFIDDLE Demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/yw4e69qo/)

There is a space on the left and at the top of the menu bar. How can I remove that space?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: always use [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or `*{margin:0; padding:0;}` which removes default styles of element which are given by browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reseting `margin & padding` : http://jsfiddle.net/yw4e69qo/1/

Simply

```
html * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But more comprehensively - dive deeper into this topic: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

It's very useful :)

Comment: Thanks. Can you describe a bit what does code does? Does this impact other elements of the page?

Comment: I think `body: 0;` should be replaced by `padding: 0;`.

Comment: My code (html * {}) just adds margin: 0 & padding: 0 to each element inside html elements (so, to each one on website :) Most of them by default have some standard paddings & margins (usually unnecessary for us). Eric Meyer's version reset more properties (it's more complex and I recommend that solution - it's professional).

Comment: About impact - yes it has impact to all other elements. But still, You should develop habit to reset all properties, and then setting them when necessary (because mostly there are unnecessary)

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#nav{
margin:0
}
```

This will solve you problem without changing the menu postiton of menu items

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}
```

Comment: Please add some details about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ul` elements always have a default `padding` on the left side because of the `list-style` property. If you inspect the element in the console you can see exactly what is creating the margins you see. So simply putting the following will fix the problem for you:

```
#nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Also you should look into using a reset.css file so you don't have to do the resetting like this yourself on every list on your page. Using **global** selectors in your css like so:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

to reset **all** elements is considered bad practice since it will slow down the execution of the code since it always have to check if the selector is part of the global selector. Hope this answer helps.